# Postgresql is not using btree index on timestamp without timezone column

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, postgresql-10

Below is my table in postgresql.

```
CREATE TABLE public.member_profile_events (
    id bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
    profileid varchar(80) NOT NULL,
    data jsonb,
    last_updated_at TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    UNIQUE (profileid)
);
CREATE INDEX member_profile_events_last_updated_at ON public.member_profile_events USING (last_updated_at);
```

I am updating last_updated_at = now() on every insert and update.

I upserted upto 350000 random rows for "profile1", "profile2",... and so on using below upsert query.

```
INSERT INTO public.member_profile_events as e (profileid, data, last_updated_at)
    values (
        'profile1',
        '{"group1": {"score": 1,"recorddate": "2018-02-01 13:15:00"}}',
        now()
    )
ON CONFLICT (profileid)
    DO UPDATE SET data = '{"group1": {"score": 1,"recorddate": "2018-02-01 13:15:00","updated":"true"}}',
            last_updated_at = now();
```

But, After running below query :

```
explain analyze select * from member_profile_events where last_updated_at = '2018-04-11 12:49:35'::timestamp;
```

I came to know that postgres is not using index on last_updated_at column. Below is output:

```
 Seq Scan on member_profile_events  (cost=0.00..570.65 rows=1 width=130) (actual time=8.490..8.490 rows=0 loops=1)
   Filter: (last_updated_at = '2018-04-11 12:49:35'::timestamp without time zone)
   Rows Removed by Filter: 17963
 Planning time: 0.282 ms
 Execution time: 8.685 ms
```

Can someone please tell me whats going wrong here.. Why postgres is not using index on last_updated_at field??

Comment: Postgres expects all rows to be returned by the condition so not using the index makes sense. You probably did not update the statistics after the bulk load. Run `analyze member_profile_events` and check the plan again

Comment: Can you elaborate on this?? I have tried with condition -  last_updated_at > '2018-03-09 13:55:31'::timestamp.  And there are 125000 rows in table which are less than or equal to '2018-03-09 13:55:31'. Rest all rows match condition - last_updated_at > '2018-03-09 13:55:31'::timestamp... Still this query is doing sequential scan.

Comment: Your new execution plan shows that there are only 17963 rows in that table. For that small number of rows a Seq Scan does make sense.

Comment: Yes, I ran analyze member_profile_events; and it returned 'ANALYZE'.

And again I ran explain analyze select * from member_profile_events where last_updated_at = '2018-04-11 12:49:35'::timestamp;

And Output is: 
 Seq Scan on member_profile_events  (cost=0.00..852.83 rows=1 width=130) (actual time=16.213..16.213 rows=0 loops=1)
   Filter: (last_updated_at = '2018-04-11 12:49:35'::timestamp without time zone)
   Rows Removed by Filter: 26832
 Planning time: 0.306 ms
 Execution time: 16.266 ms

Comment: Try running the `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` again after setting `SET enable_seqscan = off`. See if the index scan really is faster. If it is, you might want to reduce `random_page_cost` to encourage index scans.

Comment: Please do **not** post execution plans in comments.